# Images not showing on preview mode in sitecore 9.1.1

Tags: sxa, media-library

I have a website on sitecore version 9.1.1 and sxa 1.8 
 
Several components and pages contain image fields, when I open the page in edit mode everything looks fine but when I open the page in preview mode, all images do not appear. I tried inspecting to check the html rendering but the div appears to be empty in preview mode 
 
[image] 
Whereas in the edit mode, the html looks fine 
 [image]

I have different sites on the same instance but the images work fine and the issue doesn't exist on other sites, so I'm not sure what might be causing this issue on this specific site. Do I have to change something about the site settings?

Comment: When you open Preview is it correctly setting the context site in the url &sc_site=? Also, when you open SXA site manager everything is correctly configured?

Comment: Yes, everything is set correctly either in the url or in the SXA site manager

Comment: Can you please share your view implementation? Also, are you using GlassMapper?